# Angular Lazy Loading Keeps Sending to Back to Not Found

Tags: angular

I am using lazy loading for the first time. I keep getting rerouted back to the default url indicated in my app.routing-module.  Below is the code for the routing module. I did use the commented links and they workd but they are not lazy loaded.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },

  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },

  { path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent },
 // { path: 'story', component: StoryComponent },
  // {path: 'story/:id', component: StoryItemComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' },

  { path: 'story', loadChildren: () => import('./story/story.module').then(m => m.StoryModule) }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I am attempting to navigate to the /story url but it goes directly to the root url.  This is the story.module code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { StoryRoutingModule } from './story-routing.module';
import { StoryComponent } from './story.component';
import { StoryItemComponent } from './story-item/story-item.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [StoryComponent, StoryItemComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    StoryRoutingModule
  ]

})
export class StoryModule { }
```

and the story.app-routing code

```
import { StoryComponent } from './story.component';
import { StoryItemComponent } from './story-item/story-item.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: StoryComponent },
  {path: ':id', component: StoryItemComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class StoryRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ur route order is wrong it should be more specific to less specific

from top to bottom it matches ** first and its greedy route. and does not go to ur story route

Make ** as last as possible

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },

  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },

  { path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent },
 // { path: 'story', component: StoryComponent },
  // {path: 'story/:id', component: StoryItemComponent},
  { path: 'story', loadChildren: () => import('./story/story.module').then(m => m.StoryModule) },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' },
];
```

Answer (score 2):

The source of the problem is the order of the routes. Angular router checks the first matching route which is the ** and doesnt go forward. Make the **  route as the last one